# How should I implement session management/authentication on Tomcat with future OAuth implementation in mind?

Tags: security, tomcat, servlets, oauth, authentication

I'm working on a web site and I plan to use strictly OAuth in for user authentication.  I've never implemented session management/user authentication before; and so - naturally - I'm reading up on a lot of how tos to get this done.

The problem I'm running into is that a lot of examples out there for doing things like setting up your realm, authenticator, etc etc seem to rely on the user/password paradigm for authentication.  The whole point of going for OAuth is to avoid this in the first place!

That being said; I'm actually not looking for examples of full OAuth implementations right now.  I understand that I need to understand that for myself. BUT with a future OAuth implementation in mind; how should I structure my user authentication/session management FOR THE TIME BEING in a way that will allow me to move forward on developing the functionality on my site that I really care about?  I suppose I could throw some stuff together for that; but I'm just afraid that down the road I will be shoe horning an OAuth implementation as opposed to do something now which allows me to lay down the basic framework for it and then move on to other things.

So; does anyone know of a good example of laying the groundwork for OAuth on Tomcat 7?  For example, which authentication mechanism (Basic, digest, etc) I should use or how I should represent user credentials in my database?

I know that this is kind of a vague question; so I'm not expecting someone to come out and tell me all of the answers I need to know.  I'm just looking to get pointed in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Spring Security would be useful?  Your webapp could leverage Spring Security and use whatever login mechanism you need (i.e., you could do the default form-based authentication or Basic Auth for now, and replace the login/auth piece with an OAuth implementation when you're ready), but still have Spring Security manage authorization to particular resources in your webapp.

Someone has also built [OAuth for Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/index.html), so it may be a useful addition to your web app all around.

Comment: Spring was one of those things that I've seen on job ads a lot but never really looked into what it entails.  +1 for the useful info.  I'm going to walk through the tutorials then I'll mark as an answer (could take a few days).  Tks :D

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer; even though I'm not going to use it.  I'm going to reinvent the wheel and do the bulk of my security using the mechanisms available in the servlet api.  It looks like Spring would have more than met my needs and the tutorials I went through demonstrated everything you had said it did; but the more I look into user authentication the more I realize I have a lot to learn. Probably more so than I do in any other aspect of the implementation of my website.